# Mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes in Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, android-gradle-plugin, dependencies, firebase-cloud-messaging

Following are my gradle files:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "???"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 4
        versionName "1.02"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {

            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    realm {

        syncEnabled = true
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation project(':EBS')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:27.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:commons:0.9.6.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.daimajia.swipelayout:library:1.2.0@aar'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'

    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.4'
    implementation 'com.github.amlcurran.showcaseview:library:5.4.3'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

---

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {

            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'

        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
        classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.7.3'
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:5.4.1"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.2'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.4'
        classpath 'com.google.android.gms:strict-version-matcher-plugin:1.0.3'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {

            url 'https://jitpack.io'
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Here I added firebase core and firebase messaging both in my project but I am facing

> "All gms/firebase libraries must use the exact same version
>   specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found
>   versions 17.1.0, 16.2.0, 16.1.1, 16.0.1, 16.0.0, 15.0.1. Examples
>   include com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.1.0 and
>   com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:16.2.0 less... (⌘F1) 
>       There are some combinations of libraries, or tools and libraries, that are incompatible, or can lead to bugs. One such incompatibility
>   is compiling with a version of the Android support libraries that is
>   not the latest version (or in particular, a version lower than your
>   targetSdkVersion.)"

Can you please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Have you tried to clean you project?

Comment: I tried but no use.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing same problem here is how i able to resolve that issue:

As gradle is giving warning **mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes** as well as gradle will give example include so as :

> All gms/firebase libraries must use the exact same version
>   specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found
>   versions 17.1.0, 16.2.0, 16.1.1, 16.0.1, 16.0.0, 15.0.1. Examples
>   include com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.1.0 and
>   com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:16.2.0 less... (⌘F1) There are some
>   combinations of libraries, or tools and libraries, that are
>   incompatible, or can lead to bugs. One such incompatibility is
>   compiling with a version of the Android support libraries that is not
>   the latest version (or in particular, a version lower than your
>   targetSdkVersion.)

as you can see in above statement

> Examples include com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.1.0 and
>   com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:16.2.0 less...

so just add whatever depenedencies are creating version conflict and mentioned by gradle

```
implementation com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.1.0
implementation  com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:16.2.0
```

There may be chances that after adding depenedencies gradle will include more depenedencies so add those dependencies also.

Note : Gradle shows this warning because you are using some third party library which is using other

Comment: I tried your solutions but still I am getting same error.

Comment: @sAm What error you are getting same or different ?

Answer (score 0):

In your `build.gradle file`, in your repo beside:

```
maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
```

add:

```
maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
```

And according to [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android), there is no:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:16.2.0'
```

Comment: I tried your solutions but still I am getting same error.